# Taking balls out of the basket

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There are 4 baskets with numbered balls inside. In the first one, there's the numbers (3, 4, 5), in the second -  (1, 2, 3, 4), in the third - (4 , 5) and in the fourth - (1, 2, 3).

If I chose a basket randomly and take out one ball, X is the number on the ball. What is $P(2<X≤4)$?

I thought to do $P(X=3) + P(X=4)$, but firstly I need to get there. so I need to calculate the chances to get out 3 or 4 out of the baskets. so for four the chance is $1/3+1/4+1/2$. The chances to get 3 are - $1/3+1/4+1/3$. My problem is to combine it later with the Bernoulli experiments formula. Do I choose 1 ball out of all the balls in all the baskets?

Comment: Your approach will work. You just need to multiply each of your probabilities by $\frac{1}{4}$ to account for the random selection of the baskets. So, for example, $P(X=3)=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+0+\frac{1}{3})=\frac{11}{48}$.

Comment: For your last question, yes $X$ is the value of one ball out of all the balls in all the baskets.  However, not all ball has the same chance to be chosen.  For example, a ball in the first basket has probability $1/4\cdot 1/3$ to be chosen, but a ball in the second basket is chosen with probability $1/4\cdot 1/4$